# How do I zoom in the Assistant Editor "preview" of Xcode?

Tags: xcode

To visualise a storyboard, I can open the assistant editor, select "Preview" and then the storyboard. To be clear, I'm not talking about the storyboard section, I'm talking about the preview section in the assistant editor of Xcode.

How can I zoom in and out? I'm looking for menu items, keyboard shortcuts, and mouse shortcuts (with or without a trackpad).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Xcode 7:

- Double-click on the empty background area to switch between 100% zoom and 50% zoom.
- Use the pinch gesture on your trackpad.

I have yet to find a way to zoom in and out if you don't have a trackpad.

I have yet to find keyboard shortcuts that work in Xcode 7 for the assistant editor preview, I've only found keyboard shortcuts that work for the main storyboard area.